# What approaches does R use to find confidence interval for proportion?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am wondering what approaches are used in R to find the confidence interval for proportion? For example, in prop.test, it provides a confidence interval which is different from $\bar{p}-+z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\frac{\bar{p}(1-\bar{p})}{n}}$.

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question as the answers linked by @whuber do not explain the Clopper-Pearson confidence intervals provided by the function `binom.test()` in the `stats` package, which - in contrast to the approaches mentioned there - belongs to the standard installation of R.

Comment: @Michael It will be more constructive to find that answer here on CV and post a link to it.  Questions specifically about how software works are usually not on topic here.

Comment: @whuber: good point. Here is a link to our favourite site explaining the standard R approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87775/clopper-pearson-for-non-mathematicians

Comment: @Michael Thank you!  I'm sorry I missed that one.  It is now added to the list of duplicates.